# Is it possible to configure Spring Cloud Gateway with a Rewrite rule for Vue Router's history mode?

Tags: vue.js, mod-rewrite, vue-router, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway as an API-Gateway and also as a webserver hosting the static files (html/js/css) of an Vue.js SPA.

**Preclaimer**: I'm not able to change this (bad) architecture due to organisational constraints.

Currently, I'm using the default Vue Router **hash** mode, meaning client-side routing of the Vue app is accomplished via an URL hash like

```
http://hostname/#/route?parameter1=true
```

Because the Spring Cloud Gateway also acts as an Authentication gateway, it redirects to an OAuth2/OpenID SSO server, and by doing that, the route information of the URL hash is dropped after the redirect.

I'm trying to change this behaviour by switching to [Vue Router's **history** mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html), which would enable URLs like

```
http://hostname/route?parameter1=true
```

and therefore, routing information would "survive" SSO redirects.

To do that, Vue Router documentation includes [some examples for additional Webserver configuration (like mod_rewrite for Apache etc.)](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

Sadly there is no example included for my very special case ;-)

I scanned the documentation of [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#gatewayfilter-factories), but didn't find a match for this case.

So in short:

**Is it possible to configure Spring Cloud Gateway to match Vue Router's history mode requirements?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a custom `RouterFunction`:

```java
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> vueHistoryModeCatchAllRoute(
        @Value("classpath:/static/index.html") final Resource indexHtml) {
    HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> serveIndexHtmlFunction = request -> ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .bodyValue(indexHtml);
    String firstApiSegmentExcludes = "api|actuator|js|img|css|fonts|favicon\\.ico";
    return route(GET("/{path:^(?!" + firstApiSegmentExcludes + ").*}"), serveIndexHtmlFunction)
            .and(route(GET("/{path:^(?!" + firstApiSegmentExcludes + ").*}/**"),
                    serveIndexHtmlFunction));
}
```

This will serve the index.html (containing the Vue.js app) for all requests, which do not match one of the excluded paths (`firstApiSegmentExcludes`).

Answer (score 1):

You could fix it from the Spring Boot side. I mean, you could:

1. Enable the Vue Router history mode like explained in the documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)
2. Build a Spring Boot forwarding controller like this:

```java
        @RequestMapping(value = "{_:^(?!index\\.html|api).$}")
        public String redirectApi() {
            LOG.info("URL entered directly into the Browser, so we need to redirect...");
            return "forward:/";
        }
```

It basically forwards all routes to front end except: `/`, `/index.html`, `/api`, `/api/**`.

[Here](https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs#using-history-mode-for-nicer-urls) you can find a more detailed example.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I can't do it with classic Spring Boot Servlet Handlers because Spring Cloud Gateway uses Webflux. With Webflux I tried to use

RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("{_:^((?!index\\.html|api).)*$}")

which produces an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No capture groups allowed in the constraint regex: ^((?!index\.html|api).)*$